# Abstracting Java Strings data from ArrayList and manipulating it using I/O files

Tags: java, string, arraylist, io

I am a beginner. I am trying to learn 1) Read data from a file and store inside ArrayList 2) Manipulate String data 3) Output results to a new file using ArrayList.  I have figured out Part 1 and Part 3 and I have provided the code. I am having problems manipulating strings. I am sure there is an easier solution but I am not able to see it even after spending many hours. I know I need to use either charAt(i) or note.substring() or both. Maybe a nested loop?

```
// Part 1 Reading notes from a file and storing it into ArrayList named list.
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read1.txt"));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        list.add(line);
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    bufReader.close();
    list.forEach(System.out::println);//Print list to the Screen

    read1.txt  file   
    E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#
    C# E F# G# G# BAAG#   C# E F# G# C# B A G#

    May have lyrics here which needs to be avoided
    C# E G# C# B A G# G# B A G# F# A F# B G# F# D#
```

PART 2 This is where I'm having a problem. list[0]  has many different musical notes with and without #. How do I sperate each note with "," so result would look something like following. I want to keep the format same. I don't want to remove the whitespaces.

```
    E,  F#,G#, F#,G#, E,   E,F#,D#, E, C#,    E, D#, C#, B,B,  C#,C#
    C#, E, F#, G#, G#, B,A,A,G#,   C#, E, F#, G#, C#, B, A, G#,

    May have lyrics here which needs to be avoided
    C#, E, G#, C#, B, A, G#, G#, B, A, G#, F#, A, F#, B, G#, F#, D#
```

I want to store above result into another ArrayList named printToFile and I want to output the result using following code.

```
//PART 3 This code will write List to a desired new file(write2.txt)
    List<String> printToFile = new ArrayList<>();
    //here We are assuming that results have been populated into printToFile
    BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("write2.txt"));

    for (String wline : printToFile) {
        bufWriter.write(wline);
        bufWriter.newLine();
    }
    bufWriter.close();
```

Can someone pls teach me how to do Part2. I have tested Part1 and Part3. They work.  For me, this is a learning tutorial so I will WELCOME different suggestions and ideas. Thanks

Comment: ReplaceAll() method will get the desired output and it will make the life lot easier. Thanks Mr. Rudenko.  As a novice programmer, I am trying to understand the concept where you have an ArrayList and each index has different number of Strings or characters. Now you want to manipulate each string or character individually for each index and then put the results inside a different ArrayList. Eventually, I am planning to transpose each and every music note for an entire ArrayList and output the result into a new file.

Comment: I have spent lot of time playing with charAt(), note.substring() and nested loop to manipulate data in each index but I think I maybe going in a wrong direction.

Comment: you may check the update - I added a method to split the string of notes into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `replaceAll` with a regular expression to replace each note `[A-G]` followed by optional `#` and removing trailing comma:

```java
String line = "E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#";
String str = line.replaceAll("([A-G]#?)", "$1,");
if (str.endsWith(",")) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#
E,  F#,G#, F#,G#, E,   E,F#,D#, E, C#,    E, D#, C#, B,B,  C#,C#
```

*note: if the input data contain other types of notes `flat` or `sharp`, the regular expression needs to be updated accordingly.*

**update**
More advanced regular expression enables proper insertion of commas after each note except the last one (without removal of the trailing comma with additional code).

```java
String str2 = line.replaceAll("([A-G]#?+(?!$))", "$1,");
System.out.println(str2);
```

`([A-G]#?+(?!$))`:

- 1st Capturing Group `([A-G]#?+(?!$))`

  - Match a single character present in the list below `[A-G]`
    `A-G` a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `G` (index 71) (case sensitive)
  - `#?+` matches the character `#` literally (case sensitive)
    `?+` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive)
  - Negative Lookahead `(?!$)`
    Assert that the Regex below does not match
    `$` asserts position at the end of a line

[online demo](https://regexr.com/5de4j)

It also may be needed to verify if the given input string looks like a string of notes and then apply this modification to avoid inserting commas after single-letter words which might happen in the lyrics.

The matching regular expression is: `^(\s*[A-G]#?\s*)+$` - it checks if there is at least one note surrounded with optional whitespaces `\s*`.

So, the final solution would look like:

```java
private static String insertCommasIfLineOfNotes(String line) {
    if (null == line || !line.matches("^(\\s*[A-G]#?\\s*)+$")) {
        return line;
    }
    return line.replaceAll("([A-G]#?+(?!$))", "$1,");
}
```

```java
// test
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
        "E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#", 
        "A Perfect Day Elise",
        "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P"
);
lines.stream()
     .map(MyClass::insertCommasIfLineOfNotes)
     .forEach(System.out::println);

// output
E,  F#,G#, F#,G#, E,   E,F#,D#, E, C#,    E, D#, C#, B,B,  C#,C#
A Perfect Day Elise
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
```

**update 2**
If it is needed to get a list of substrings in the line of notes, containing plain notes `A`..`G` optionally followed by `#`, or sequences of 1 or more whitespaces, the following methods can be implemented.
*refactored to add whitespace sequences to appropriate note entry to facilitate joining of the notes into single string*

```java
private static List<String> buildListOfNotes(String line) {
    if (null == line || !line.matches("^(\\s*[A-G]#?\\s*)+$")) {
        return Arrays.asList(line); // for lyrics line
    }
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
      
    int spaceStart = -1;
    int spaceEnd = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++) {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        boolean note = isNote(c);
        
        if (isNote(c)) {
            String prefix = "";
            if (spaceStart > -1) {
                // add existing whitespace as a prefix to current note
                int prevResult = result.size() - 1;
                prefix = line.substring(spaceStart, spaceEnd);
                spaceStart = -1;
            }
            if (line.charAt(i + 1) == '#') {
                result.add(prefix + line.substring(i, i + 2));
                i++;
            } else {
                result.add(prefix + line.substring(i, i + 1));
                if (!isNote(line.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    spaceStart = i + 1;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (spaceStart == -1) {
                spaceStart = i;
                spaceEnd = i + 1;
            } else {
                spaceEnd++;
            }
        }
      }
      if (spaceStart > -1) {
          // add trailing whitespace if available to the last note
          int prevResult = result.size() - 1;
          result.set(prevResult, result.get(prevResult) + line.substring(spaceStart));
      }
      return result;
  }
  
  private static boolean isNote(char c) {
      return c >= 'A' && c <= 'G';
  }
```

```java
// testing method to retrieve list of substring
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
        "E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#",
        "E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C#    ",
        "   E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C",
        "   E  F#G# F#G# E   EF#D# E C#    E D# C# BB  C#C ", 
        "A Perfect Day Elise",
        "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P"
);
lines.stream()
     .map(MyClass::buildListOfNotes)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Test output (*"note" entry may include whitespace sequence*):

```
[E,  F#, G#,  F#, G#,  E,   E, F#, D#,  E, C#,     E, D#,  C#,  B, B, C#, C#]
[E,  F#, G#,  F#, G#,  E,   E, F#, D#,  E, C#,     E, D#,  C#,  B, B, C#, C#    ]
[   E,  F#, G#,  F#, G#,  E,   E, F#, D#,  E, C#,     E, D#,  C#,  B, B, C#]
[   E,  F#, G#,  F#, G#,  E,   E, F#, D#,  E, C#,     E, D#,  C#,  B, B, C#, C ]
[A Perfect Day Elise]
[A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P]
```

Then the array of notes can be easily converted into String using `String.join`:

```java
// lineToWrite will contain original whitespaces
String lineToWrite = String.join(",", buildListOfNotes(line));

// cleanLine will contain notes without extra spacing
String cleanLine = buildListOfNotes(line).stream()
                                         .map(String::trim)
                                         .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: As a newbie I was trying to figure this question out, and all of sudden you nailed it:)
Would you please explain this part for me: "([A-H]#?)", "$1,"
Thank you @AlexRudenko

Comment: `([A-H]#?)` - is a regular expression to match a group consisting of the 1 character from the range from `A` to `H`, followed by `#` which is optional as indicated by `?` quantifier.  Expression `$1,` means that each matching group is replaced by itself `$1` followed by the comma.

Comment: yeah, the problem with it is that includes non-existing note `H`

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Rudenko for your great effort and your help.  :)

Comment: @Nathan Glad if it was helpful for you.  Though I don't quite understand the requirement about conversion to the list of notes and then printing this list after additional processing to make it a valid string :)

Comment: @Alex As a novice, I spent too many hours working with charAt(),substring(), ArrayList and loops to derive the desired results so I wanted to see where I was making a mistake. Your code cleared the concept. What you did with replaceAll() was amazing. Thanks

Comment: @Nathan, if the answer was really helpful for you could you [accept it by pressing a tick](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?  Thank you.

Comment: @Alex  Can you use functions inside ReplaceAll()? If you are shifting a music notes up by given number of halfsteps then can you use ReplaceAll() for that?
 SCALE_SHARPS = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
I know how to find the “input” note on the scale and move it up by given number of halfsteps and  print the note from that index. It works. Can it be done using ReplaceAll() with the same  input notes I've used above.

Comment: @Nathan, I'm not sure this could be possible and `replaceAll` does not fit well for remapping of the values (each existing value needs to be replaced with specific new value), so 12 cycles are needed to replace old value with the new one (new marked lower case) and then calling `toUpperCase`, while with loop you can do this in one run.  [Similar question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/regex/comments/6vggaq/would_it_be_possible_to_write_a_caesar_cipher/) has negative answer.